# MVVM without DataBinding

Tags: mvvm, kotlin

I started learning Kotlin to develop Android applications and for my first project I have to use MVVM as pattern to separate the presentation layer from the logic. All the articles I've found about MVVM use DataBinding library to bind the data of the models directly to the xml views. I worked a little with DataBinding in Java but I doesn't like it because it is very difficult to find errors when binding is wrong. My questions is if there is another way to use MVVM without DataBinding?

Comment: I use MVVM without databinding - feels good. Just bind to `ViewModel`'s `LiveData`s during initialization of `Fragment` \ `Activity`, etc.

Comment: Thank you. Today I read a little about LiveData and it seems to be amazing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it is. Just abstract example: imagine `ViewModel`:

```
class SomeViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private lateinit var roadmap: RoleScreenRoadmap
    private lateinit var uiScope: CoroutineScope

    private val _nameRequired = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    private val _userName = MutableLiveData<String>()

    val nameRequired: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _nameRequired
    val userName: LiveData<String>
        get() = _userName

    ...
}
```

And now `Activity`:

```
class AbstractActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: RoleScreenViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_some)
        initializeDependencies()
        performBindings()
    }

    private fun initializeDependencies() {
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AbstractViewModel::class.java)
    }



    private fun performBindings() {
        val lifecycle = ::getLifecycle
        viewModel.nameRequired.observe(lifecycle) { nameRequired: Boolean? ->
            if (nameRequired!!) {
                showNameInputWindow()
            }
        }
        viewModel.userName.observe(lifecycle, ::setTitle)
    }

    ...
}
```

You can just subscribe during android's lifecycle component initialization and no databinding is ever needed.

Comment: Can you tell me how to handle onClickButtons without data binding please?

Comment: @MijaelViricochea, just `myButton.setOnClickListener { viewModel.onButtonClicked() }`